# How can I fix "Failed to execute script" error

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I want to convert my `.py` file to `.exe` for running the program with double click. I'm using pyinstaller and this is my cmd code: `pyinstaller -w examples2.py`

When the task completed successfully I'm trying to run `examples2.exe` in `dist` folder. When I double click it, cmd screen is opening and it gives error **Failed to execute script examples2**.

When I searched for the error, I saw that there could be a Path error. My path file is the Scripts file inside the file where Anaconda is installed.

Here is my screen shot. [image: ss]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213536/discussion-on-question-by-miracdogan-how-can-i-fix-failed-to-execute-script-er).